# How to do vlookup and hlookup together in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as such:

```
interestRates <- c(0,0.005,0.015)
FXandGold <- c(0.01,0.05,0.075)
Equities <- c(0.06,0.08,0.1)
PreciousMetalsandGold <- c(0.07,0.07,0.08)
OtherCommodities <-c(0.1,0.12,0.15)
Timehorizon <- c("One year or less", "Over one year to five years", "Over five years")
Addondatatable<-data.frame(Timehorizon,interestRates,FXandGold,Equities,PreciousMetalsandGold,OtherCommodities)
Addondatatable
                  Timehorizon interestRates FXandGold Equities PreciousMetalsandGold OtherCommodities
1            One year or less         0.000     0.010     0.06                  0.07             0.10
2 Over one year to five years         0.005     0.050     0.08                  0.07             0.12
3             Over five years         0.015     0.075     0.10                  0.08             0.15
```

How to lookup for the addon where the it is one year or less and it is Equities? So the value should be returned as 0.06.

Btw, is there a better way to create this mappingtable?

I am new to R, need some guidance on these..

Comment: I'd take a look at the tidyverse package or any new course that outlines it, such as the one by David Robinson at DataCamp. It will answer all of these questions for you and get you going quickly.

Comment: Read [this chapter](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/subsetting-r-objects.html) about subsetting in R.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by 'it's Equities'. What values? Can you elaborate on that? With regards to subsetting of `Timehorizon`, you will have to come up with an algorithm or a list of levels which are 'game' for subestting. If the set of values is small, you can do that with a simple vector, e.g. `x[x$Timehorizon %in% c("One year or less"), "Equities", drop = FALSE]`. If there is more than one values, you would just append another value to that `c()`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik it shld return 0.06.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a minor modification to your table, this is easy.  Instead of making Timehorizon be a column, make it be the row.names. Then you can just directly use it to query the table.

```
Addondatatable<-data.frame(interestRates,FXandGold,Equities,
        PreciousMetalsandGold,OtherCommodities, row.names=Timehorizon)

Addondatatable["One year or less", "Equities"]
[1] 0.06
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow p0bs suggestion and read up on tidyverse. It sounds like you're after:

```
library(tidyverse)
Addondatatable %>% filter(Timehorizon == "One year or less") %>% select(Equities)
```

Comment: This works fine, if you're fine with introducing a boat load of dependencies for something that R's been designed to do out of the box. :)